# notifyDataSetChanges for list adapter, modify only part of the view

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

*This is propably strange question, and i understand if here will be downvotes*

So i have a custom adapter(with using ViewHolder pattern) that have such views:

```
    private class ViewHolder {
        ImageView chatImage;
        TextView chatName;
        TextView lastMessage;
        TextView lastMessageTime;
        TextView unreadMessagesCount;
        //ViewStub avatarsViewStub;
    }

    private ViewHolder createViewHolder (View view) {
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.chatImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.chat_image);
        holder.chatName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.chat_participant_name);
        holder.lastMessage = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.last_message);
        holder.lastMessageTime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.last_message_time);
        holder.unreadMessagesCount = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.unread_messages_count);
        return holder;
    }
```

`TextView unreadMessagesCount` is suppose to show number of unread messages, and whenever new message coming it should be updated. But as you can see there are lot of `Views` and my goal here is : **Update only unreadMessagesCount instead of calling whole `getView` whenever `adapter.notifyDataSetChanges()` is called**, i want to know if it's possible

**Edit** : i've posted my current solution as one of the answers, but we still looking for better approach

Comment: i dont think it will be possible. I will be interested to know though

Answer (score 0):

You can update only the required views in a list item of your `ListView`. By using below method you can get view of the listitem at the given position.

```
public View getViewByPosition(int position) {
    final int firstListItemPosition = filesListview.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    final int lastListItemPosition = firstListItemPosition + filesListview.getChildCount() - 1;
    if (position < firstListItemPosition || position > lastListItemPosition) {
        // return filesListview.getAdapter().getView(position, filesListview.getChildAt(position), filesListview);
        return null;
    } else {
        final int childIndex = position - firstListItemPosition;
        return filesListview.getChildAt(childIndex);
    }
}
```

After getting the view in the particular position you can get the `ViewHolder` by using `getTag()` and update the data.

```
View listItem = getViewByPosition(position);
if(listItem!=null){
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
   //Update the data
}
```

Comment: It seems like it won't update UI without __notifyDataSetChanged()__ call anyway, am i lost something? I make UI changes by getting View in my Fragment class(wihich stores listView)

Comment: No it is an working sample, i had already tried it without notifyDataSetChanged(),
The above method will return the view of the listitem if the view at the given position is visible otherwise it will return null.

Comment: While doing this you need to update the data in the list associating with the ListAdapter to keep your data consistent ,

Comment: ok tell me where do you getting the problem? 
does that method returning any view or it is returning null?

Comment: When i've changed it, changes won't appear until notifyDataSetChanges is called

Comment: do you get any view by calling the above method with a position?